# How does thermal energy work?

Tags: energy

Say I push a block along a floor with 10 Newtons of force along a floor and the friction pushes back with 4 N. The by Newton’s third law wouldn’t the block push on the floor with 4 N as well? Why doesn’t it get converted to kinetic energy rather than thermal energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the block does indeed push on the earth with that same force but opposite. And some kinetic energy *is* given to the earth.

But remember that the momentum conservation law must be fulfilled as well.* That law tells us that due to the comparatively enormous mass of the earth, the earth will gain almost no speed.

Almost no speed means almost no kinetic energy. In conclusion, almost all of the work done to push the object is converted into kinetic energy of the object.

---

<sup>* Both the **momentum conservation law** as well as the **angular momentum conservation law** must be fulfilled and will be rekavant here, since we would expect friction to cause earth to rotate.</sup>